# How to find the path of particular property in a complex class?

Tags: c#, class, reflection, properties, path

I am using HTTP patch to update a single property value. I want to find the path dynamically which is residing under a complex class.

For example consider this is my class structure.

```
    public class A
    {
      public B b;
    }
    public class B
    {
      public C c;
    }
    public class C
    {
      public string ca;
      public string cb;
    }
```

I want to find the path of a particular property "ca". So it should return b/c/ca.

So once it returns the path i can find that property and update with value.

Comment: I guess you will need to code that functionality

Comment: I am using HTTP patch. So i want to update a particular property. So if i give the path it should return that property based on that path.

Comment: @mjwills updated my post. Thanks